# How can I do this internship report template?

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, templates

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{article}
{
Template Source Code
}
\begin{document}
\duty= Soldering         % Duty Title
\pername= Me             % Personnel Name Title
\department= Storehouse  % Department Title
Bla... Bla...
\newpage
\duty= Disassembly       % Duty Title
\pername= You            % Personnel Name Title
\department= Storehouse  % Department Title

Bla... Bla...
\newpage
...
\end{document}
```

I want to do picture in below. But I could not. Content of Duty, Personnel Name and Department cells may be different in every page. Anyway, Page Number automatic. The next page will variables reset every `\newpage` is added. I'm waiting for your helps.

[image]

**Partially My Solve:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=3cm,bottom=1.5cm,marginparwidth=0cm,marginparsep=0cm,outer=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\fancyhead[RO,RE,LO,LE]{\textbf{{
\begin{textblock*}{5cm}(1.5cm,1.5cm)\begin{minipage}{5cm}Duty: \end{minipage}\end{textblock*}
\begin{textblock*}{5cm}(15cm,1.5cm)\begin{minipage}{5cm}Page Number: \thepage\ / \pageref{LastPage}\end{minipage}\end{textblock*}
\begin{textblock*}{5cm}(1.5cm,27.5cm)\begin{minipage}{5cm}Personnel Name: \end{minipage}\end{textblock*}
\begin{textblock*}{5cm}(10cm,27.5cm)\begin{minipage}{5cm}Date:\end{minipage}\end{textblock*}
\begin{textblock*}{5cm}(15cm,27.5cm)\begin{minipage}{5cm}Department:\end{minipage}\end{textblock*}
}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{textblock*}{5cm}(3cm-.6cm,1.5cm)\begin{minipage}{5cm}Soldering\end{minipage}\end{textblock*}
\begin{textblock*}{5cm}(1.5cm-.6cm,28cm)\begin{minipage}{5cm}Me\end{minipage}\end{textblock*}
\begin{textblock*}{5cm}(10cm-.6cm,28cm)\begin{minipage}{5cm}Date\end{minipage}\end{textblock*}
\begin{textblock*}{5cm}(15cm-.6cm,28cm)\begin{minipage}{5cm}Storehouse\end{minipage}\end{textblock*}

\lipsum[1-5]

\newpage

\begin{textblock*}{5cm}(3cm-.6cm,1.5cm)\begin{minipage}{5cm}Disassembly\end{minipage}\end{textblock*}
\begin{textblock*}{5cm}(1.5cm-.6cm,28cm)\begin{minipage}{5cm}You\end{minipage}\end{textblock*}
\begin{textblock*}{5cm}(10cm-.6cm,28cm)\begin{minipage}{5cm}Date\end{minipage}\end{textblock*}
\begin{textblock*}{5cm}(15cm-.6cm,28cm)\begin{minipage}{5cm}Storehouse\end{minipage}\end{textblock*}

\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDED SITUATION***

While I added/changed `\lhead{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-a}\bf{Duty: \it\Theduty}}`

There is no space in Page One.

[image]

But there is a space in Page Two, Three ... . That is a normal. How fix it?
[image]

**Added to Zarko's answer...**

```
...
\checkoddpage 
\ifoddpage
\node (f1) [NL,wt=181,ht=287,
        above right=5mm and 20mm of current page.south west] {};% <-- frame anchor
\draw   (f1.west) -- + (-1,0);
\else
\node (f1) [NL,wt=181,ht=287,
        above right=5mm and 12mm of current page.south west] {};% <--     frame anchor
\draw   (f1.east) -- + (1,0);
 \fi 
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**edit:**
meanwhile i found the way how to avoid limitation of this solution to only one page. with use package `everypage` and slightly rearranged and simplified code in the first *mwe* now the "duty" can have any number of pages:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
                babel,
                backgrounds,
                calc,
                positioning,
                }
\usepackage[showframe,
            a4paper,
            ignoreall,
            hmargin={25mm,10mm},%
            vmargin={20mm,20mm}%
            ]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{everypage}

\usepackage{lipsum}

%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\newcounter{okvir}
\newsavebox{\name}
\newsavebox{\duty}
\newsavebox{\school}

\newcommand{\okvir}[3]{%
\clearpage
    \sbox{\name}{#1}
    \sbox{\duty}{#2}
    \sbox{\school}{#3}
\noindent
%    \setcounter{page}{1} % use in the case when each duty should start with page number 1
\AddEverypageHook{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay,
    node distance=0mm,
NL/.style = {draw, line width=0.7mm,
             inner xsep=2mm, inner ysep=0mm, outer sep=0mm,
             font=\bfseries\sffamily,
             align=left},
wt/.style = {text width=##1 mm},
ht/.style = {minimum height=##1 mm}
                    ]
\node (f1) [NL,wt=181,ht=287,
            above right=5mm and 20mm of current page.south west] {};% <-- frame anchor
\node (f2) [NL,wt=148,ht=10,
            below right=of f1.north west] {Duty:~\usebox{\duty}};%\
\node (f3) [NL,wt=29,ht=10,
            right=of f2] {page \thepage~of~\pageref{LastPage}};
\node (f4) [NL,wt=88,ht=10,
            above right=of f1.south west] {Personal name:~\usebox{\name}};%
\node (f5) [NL,wt=89,ht=10,
            right=of f4]  {Department:~\usebox{\school}};%
\draw   (f1.west) -- + (-1,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }% end of every page hook
                    }% end of newcommand
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\okvir{NAME}{DUTY}{11th SCHOOL}
\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum[1]

%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\okvir{Joe Doe}{Joe Doe task}{department unknown}
\lipsum\lipsum

\end{document}
```

*mwe* still had to be compiled at least twice.

in cases, that each task, i.e. duty had to start with page number 1, then only you need to remove % on beginning of the line `\setcounter{page}{1}` (see *mwe*)

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**addendum:**
for two side documents the "okvir" (frame) had to be aware if page number is odd or even. for this you need add to it simple test with `\isodd`:

```
\newcommand{\okvir}[3]{%
\cleardoublepage    % new tasks starts on odd pages
% \clearpage        % new tasks starts on any pages
    \sbox{\name}{#1}
    \sbox{\duty}{#2}
    \sbox{\school}{#3}
\noindent
%    \setcounter{page}{1} % use in the case when each duty should start with page number 1
\AddEverypageHook{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay,
    node distance=0mm,
NL/.style = {draw, line width=0.7mm,
             inner xsep=2mm, inner ysep=0mm, outer sep=0mm,
             font=\bfseries\sffamily,
             align=left},
wt/.style = {text width=##1 mm},
ht/.style = {minimum height=##1 mm}
                    ]
\ifodd\value{page}
\node (f1) [NL,wt=181,ht=287,
            above right=5mm and 20mm of current page.south west] {};% <-- odd frame anchor
\else
\node (f1) [NL,wt=181,ht=287,
            above right=5mm and 5mm of current page.south west] {};% <-- even  frame anchor
\fi            
\node (f2) [NL,wt=148,ht=10,
            below right=of f1.north west] {Duty:~\usebox{\duty}};%\
\node (f3) [NL,wt=29,ht=10,
            right=of f2] {page \thepage~of~\pageref{LastPage}};
\node (f4) [NL,wt=88,ht=10,
            above right=of f1.south west] {Personal name:~\usebox{\name}};%
\node (f5) [NL,wt=89,ht=10,
            right=of f4]  {Department:~\usebox{\school}};%
\draw   (f1.west) -- + (-1,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }% end of every page hook
                    }% end of newcommand
```

[image]

*note:* code for `okvir` is not aware if document use option `twoside`. if you like to have this feature too, please ask new question :).

Comment: It works good working, too. @Zarko.

Comment: @Özgür, of course it works :) :) :) . please see edit of answer. in it remove limitation of the first solution (to use on only one page) and slightly simplified code ...

Comment: I would like to ask a question to you @Zarko. If `\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}` How will pages' frame shift to left at the even pages? See the edited your answers' below.

Comment: @Özgür I rejected your edit of Zarko's answer as it seems you were using it to ask a followup question. Please do so by editing your original question instead, as the answer space is meant *only* for answers.

Comment: @Troy, Okay....

Comment: @Zarko How is it my solve? Below the my question.

Comment: @Özgür, see addendum to my answer.

Comment: Exactly working. [CLOSED]

Comment: what means "closed"? if above answer solve your problem on the best way, please accept it.

Comment: @Zarko ,  Of course immediately I accepted.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe something like?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=3cm,bottom=1.5cm,marginparwidth=0cm,marginparsep=0cm,outer=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\newcommand{\Theduty}{}
\newcommand{\duty}[1]{\renewcommand{\Theduty}{#1}}
\newcommand{\Thepername}{}
\newcommand{\pername}[1]{\renewcommand{\Thepername}{#1}}
\newcommand{\Thedepartment}{}
\newcommand{\department}[1]{\renewcommand{\Thedepartment}{#1}}

\lhead{Duty: \Theduty}
\chead{}
\rhead{Page Number: \thepage\ / \pageref{LastPage}}
\lfoot{Personnel Name: \Thepername}
\cfoot{Date: \today}
\rfoot{Department: \Thedepartment}

\setlength{\headheight}{13.6pt}

\begin{document}

\duty{Soldering}         % Duty Title
\pername{Me}             % Personnel Name Title
\department{Storehouse}  % Department Title

\lipsum[1-5]

\newpage
\duty{Disassembly}       % Duty Title
\pername{You}            % Personnel Name Title
\department{Storehouse}  % Department Title

\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

*EDIT*

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=3cm,bottom=1.5cm,marginparwidth=0cm,marginparsep=0cm,outer=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\newcommand{\Theduty}{}
\newcommand{\duty}[1]{\renewcommand{\Theduty}{#1}}
\newcommand{\Thepername}{}
\newcommand{\pername}[1]{\renewcommand{\Thepername}{#1}}
\newcommand{\Thedepartment}{}
\newcommand{\department}[1]{\renewcommand{\Thedepartment}{#1}}

%\lhead{Duty: \Theduty} %<-- 
\lhead{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-a} Duty: \Theduty}
\chead{}
\rhead{Page Number: \thepage\ / \pageref{LastPage}}
\lfoot{Personnel Name: \Thepername}
\cfoot{Date: \today}
\rfoot{Department: \Thedepartment}

\setlength{\headheight}{33pt}

\begin{document}

\duty{Soldering}         % Duty Title
\pername{Me}             % Personnel Name Title
\department{Storehouse}  % Department Title
\lipsum[1-5]
\newpage
\duty{Disassembly}       % Duty Title
\pername{You}            % Personnel Name Title
\department{Storehouse}  % Department Title
\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please see my edited question, @samcarter.

Comment: @Özgür See my edited answer. You should have gotten a warning which tells you explicitly what you have to change: `\headheight is too small (13.6pt): Make it at least 32.53278pt.`

Comment: @Özgür Don't use commands like `\bf`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516/does-it-matter-if-i-use-textit-or-it-bfseries-or-bf-etc

Comment: I got it. I Don't use it any more.

Comment: I learned for this question a lot from you.  @samcarter.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution, which does pretty much what you want.

It uses TikZ for the the graphics and `scrlayer-scrpage` to get the frame into a page style. You can adapt the distance between text and frame and the height for head and foot (here they are always the same height).

Note: the frame is drawn into the margin, therefore the latter will appear to be smaller then set. Add `\fsep` to get the desired margin.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% distance from text to frame
\newlength{\fsep}
\setlength{\fsep}{20pt}
% height of head and foot
\newlength{\hfheight}
\setlength{\hfheight}{2\baselineskip}

\geometry{margin=2cm, % can be adapted, real margin is 2cm-\fsep
  % it is possible to write margin=\dimexpr2cm+\fsep to get exact margin
  % next line needed for the way the frame is defined
  includehead,includefoot,headheight=\hfheight,footskip=\hfheight,headsep=0pt
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\@duty}{}
\newcommand*{\duty}[1]{\def\@duty{#1}}
\newcommand*{\@pername}{}
\newcommand*{\pername}[1]{\def\@pername{#1}}
\newcommand*{\@department}{}
\newcommand*{\department}[1]{\def\@department{#1}}

\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalcolor}

\newlength{\hfdepth}
\setlength{\hfdepth}{0pt}

\tikzset{%
  hfnode/.style={%
    draw,outer sep=0pt,inner xsep=\fsep,
    minimum height=\hfheight,
    text depth=\hfdepth,
    align=left
  },
  headnodeleft/.style={hfnode,
    anchor=south west,
    minimum width=0.6\textwidth+\fsep,
    text width=0.6\textwidth-\fsep
  },
  headnoderight/.style={hfnode,
    anchor=south east,
    minimum width=0.4\textwidth+\fsep,
    text width=0.4\textwidth-\fsep
  },
  footnodeleft/.style={hfnode,
    anchor=north west,
    minimum width=0.6\textwidth+\fsep,
    text width=0.6\textwidth-\fsep
  },
  footnoderight/.style={hfnode,
    anchor=north east,
    minimum width=0.4\textwidth+\fsep,
    text width=0.4\textwidth-\fsep
  }
}

\DeclareNewLayer[%
  textarea,background,
  contents={%
    \tikz{%
      \useasboundingbox(0,0)rectangle(\layerwidth,\layerheight);
      \draw(-\fsep,-\fsep)rectangle(\layerwidth+\fsep,\layerheight+\fsep);
      % note: \hfill can be replaced by a space or e.g. \quad
      \node[headnodeleft] at (-\fsep,\layerheight+\fsep) {\normalfont
        \usekomafont{pageheadfoot}\usekomafont{pagehead}Duty:\hfill\@duty};
      \node[headnoderight] at (\layerwidth+\fsep,\layerheight+\fsep) {\normalfont
        \usekomafont{pageheadfoot}\usekomafont{pagehead}Page Number:\hfill\pagemark};
      \node[footnodeleft] at (-\fsep,-\fsep) {\normalfont
        \usekomafont{pageheadfoot}\usekomafont{pagefoot}Personal Name:\hfill\@pername};
      \node[footnoderight] at (\layerwidth+\fsep,-\fsep) {\normalfont
        \usekomafont{pageheadfoot}\usekomafont{pagefoot}Department:\hfill\@department};
    }%
  }%
]{reportframe}

\DeclareNewPageStyleByLayers{reportframe}{reportframe}
\pagestyle{reportframe}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\duty{Soldering}         % Duty Title
\pername{Me}             % Personnel Name Title
\department{Storehouse}  % Department Title
\noindent
\lipsum[1]

\vfill\noindent
\lipsum[2]

\newpage
\duty{Disassembly}       % Duty Title
\pername{You}            % Personnel Name Title
\department{Storehouse}  % Department Title
\noindent
\lipsum[1]

\vfill\noindent
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Good and troublesome working. I will try. @Mike