# How to draw a rectangle and table in the header together?

Tags: tikz-pgf, header-footer

I am trying to generate a template like this, a border and a table-like **header and footer for all pages**

[image]

Here is the code that I put together

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[
top=25.4mm,
bottom=25.4mm,
left=25.4mm,
right=25.4mm
]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
%This is to draw a rectangle as border
\fancyhead[L]{\tikz[overlay, remember picture] {
\draw ([shift={(24pt,-24pt)}]current page.north west) rectangle ++(544pt,-794pt);
%This is to draw the table
\begin{tabular}{|m{3.0cm}|m{10.0cm}|m{2.5cm}|}
      \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Photometry and Radiometry Calibration Document} \\ \hline
        PAR 117  & 
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Revision\\ Issue
\end{tabular}
\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
} }
```

***Note that I am drawing a rectangle in the header as the border for all pages***, but I either get the border or the tables and not both at the same time.

Can someone fix the issue or give a tip? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). It is much easier to help you if we can start with some compilable code that illustrates your problem. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, include any necessary packages and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. At the moment we have to guess what packages etc you are using before we can compile your code.

Comment: @Andrew : Thanks for your comment and answer. I just added all my code.

Comment: I prefer everypage and tikzpagenodes for elaborate headers, especially if they don't match \textwidth.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276358/text-on-background-image-footer-and-header/276453?r=SearchResults&s=10|18.8575#276453 for example.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/385252/how-can-i-do-this-internship-report-template. Your question is pretty much duplicate to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example using `tikz-page`. You can use macros instead of fixed test inside header/footer to make it more handy.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
% set top/bottom margin to adjust text space
\usepackage[margin=1in, top=1.6in, bottom=1.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-page}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{datetime2}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

% border line style
\tikzset{
    pageborder/.style={line width=0.5mm},
    plainnode/.style={inner sep=0mm, outer sep=0mm}
}

% no header line
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

% add paddings to cells
\newcommand\myvertspacea{\vspace*{1ex}}
\newcommand\mystructa{\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}}
\newcommand\myvertspaceb{\vspace*{2ex}}

% set page layout
\newcommand{\tikzpagelayout}{
    % move anchors a little bit for better borders
    \coordinate (newnorthwest) at ($(page.northwest)+(0.1mm, -0.1mm)$);
    \coordinate (newnortheast) at ($(page.northeast)+(-0.2mm, -0.1mm)$);
    \coordinate (newsouthwest) at ($(page.southwest)+(0.1mm, 0.1mm)$);
    \coordinate (newsoutheast) at ($(page.southeast)+(-0.2mm, 0.1mm)$);

    % draw border
    \draw[pageborder] (newnorthwest) -- (newsouthwest) -- (newsoutheast) 
        -- (newnortheast) -- (newnorthwest);
        
    % draw header
    % use yshift to lower the table a bit
    \node[plainnode, text width=0.9\linewidth, yshift=-2cm] at (page.north) {
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|>{\centering}m{0.9\linewidth}|}{%
        \bgroup\bfseries\large\myvertspacea
        Photometry and Raiometry\\ Calibration Document \egroup} \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|>{\centering}m{0.6\linewidth}|}{%
            \textbf{PAR-117} Spectral Irridiance Standards: Operating Procedure\\
            (A33-06-04-01 to A33-06-04-04)} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{p{0.3\linewidth}|}{%
            \begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}ll}
            \mystructa Revision: & 1.6\\
            Issue Date: & 1999-Apr-09\\
            Issued By: & AAG\\
            Effective: & 2009-Jun-30
            \end{tabular}
        }\\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \par
    };
    
    
    % draw footer
    \node[plainnode, text width=0.9\linewidth, yshift=2cm] at (page.south) {
        \centering
        \bgroup
        \small
        \begin{tabular}{|m{0.35\linewidth}|p{0.35\linewidth}|c|}
        \hline
        \myvertspaceb\textbf{Approved by:}\myvertspaceb
        & \textbf{Date:}  
        & \multicolumn{1}{p{0.2\linewidth}|}{\centering\textbf{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}} \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \egroup
        };

}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}

\Blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure that you need `tikz` for this as I think that the `fancyhdr` package and a few `tabular` environments suffice to produce:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
% remember the number of the last page
\AtEndDocument{\label{P:LastPage}}

% placeholder commands for data in the header and footer
\providecommand\Unit{PAR-117}
\providecommand\Description{Spectral Irradiance Standards:\newline Operating procedure\newline(A33-06-04-01 to A33-06-04-04)}
\providecommand\Revision{1.6}
\providecommand\IssueDate{1999-Apr-09}
\providecommand\IssuedBy{AAG}
\providecommand\Effective{2009-Jun-30}
\providecommand\ApprovedBy{The Supreme Approver}
\providecommand\ApprovalDate{2016-11-12}

% the header and footer
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt}
\newcommand\HeadStrut{\vrule height 2em depth 1.5em width 0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
%This is to draw a rectangle as border
\renewcommand\headrule{} % disable header rule
\fancyhead[C]{%
  \begin{tabular}{|m{0.60\textwidth}|m{0.35\textwidth}|}\hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\bfseries\large Photometry and Radiometry Calibration Document\HeadStrut}\\
    \hline
    \begin{tabular}{lm{75mm}}
         \bfseries\Unit & \Description
    \end{tabular}
    &
    \begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
        \textbf{Revision:}  & \Revision\\
        \textbf{Issue date} & \IssueDate\\
        \textbf{Issued by:} & \IssuedBy\\
        \textbf{Effective}  & \Effective\\
    \end{tabular}
    \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
}
\fancyfoot[C]{
  \begin{tabular}{|m{0.5\textwidth}|m{0.2\textwidth}|m{0.2\textwidth}|}\hline
     \textbf{Approved by:}~\ApprovedBy &
     \textbf{Date:}~\ApprovalDate &
     Page \thepage~of~\pageref{P:LastPage}\\
     \hline
  \end{tabular}
}
\begin{document}
  blah
  \newpage
  blah
\end{document}
```

In particular, I have defined the following 'placeholder commands' at the top of the document for the data in the header and footer.

```
\providecommand\Unit{PAR-117}
\providecommand\Description{Spectral Irradiance Standards:\newline Operating procedure\newline(A33-06-04-01 to A33-06-04-04)}
\providecommand\Revision{1.6}
\providecommand\IssueDate{1999-Apr-09}
\providecommand\IssuedBy{AAG}
\providecommand\Effective{2009-Jun-30}
\providecommand\ApprovedBy{The Supreme Approver}
\providecommand\ApprovalDate{2016-11-12}
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Apparently I did not clearly explain my issue. I am drawing a rectangle as the page border + a table in the header. I guess you did not get that part so your code is not drawing border and this is why I used tikz package.